# Error: Variable-sized object may not be initialized. But why?

Tags: iphone, memory-management

```
enter code hereint quantity = [array count];
int i;
for (i=0; i<quantity; i++) 
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Car_%@.jpg",  [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"CarName"]]   ];
    UIImage *img[i] = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imgView[i] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img[i]];
    imgView[i].frame = CGRectMake(i*kWidth, 0, kWidth, kHeight);
    [scrollView addSubview:imgView[i]];
    [imgView[i] release];
}`enter code here`
```

Error: Variable-sized object may not be initialized. But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this:

```
int i;
for (i=0; i<quantity; i++) 
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Car_%@.jpg",  [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"CarName"]]   ];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    imgView.frame = CGRectMake(i*kWidth, 0, kWidth, kHeight);
    [scrollView addSubview:imgView];
    [imgView release];
}
```

You don't need to use img[i] in order to populate a scrollview with UIImageView.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> UIImage *img[i] = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
> ```

This declares a C-style array of size `i` and attempts to initialise it with an instance of `UIImage`.  That doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to do?  Where is the rest of your code?

Edit:

Okay, I think I see what you are doing.  Just get rid of all the places you have `[i]`.  Inside the loop, you are only dealing with one item at a time, and even if you weren't, that's not how you use arrays.