# gcc complains: variable-sized object may not be initialized

Tags: c, gcc, gcc4

I've looked at these and they do not answer my question:

[variable-sized object may not be initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688219/variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized)

[C compile error: "Variable-sized object may not be initialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082914/c-compile-error-variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized)

[Error: Variable-sized object may not be initialized. But why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550653/error-variable-sized-object-may-not-be-initialized-but-why)

I am trying to write some fairly portable `c` code:

```
int main () 
{
    const int foo=13;
    int bar[foo]={0};
    return 0;
}
```

I get a `variable-sized object may not be initialized` error when compiling as `c` code using either:

- **gcc 4.3.4**
- **arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc 4.4.5**

And if i compile it as `c` in **VS2008** i get a slightly different `error C2057: expected constant expression`

I understand that here, the `c` code compiler is not recognising `const int foo=13;` to be truly constant; for example we might have

```
void a(int fool) 
{    
    const int foo=fool;
    int bar[foo]={0};
}
```

I also realise that [unlike the gcc compilers](http://ideone.com/jbx7h), the **VS2008** compiler has no concept of [C99 variable-length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99). And that MS apparently has not mentioned any future support.

And yet, `cpp` code compilation with either **gcc** or **MS** compilers is altogether different/cleverer ?!

- [this fails to compile](http://ideone.com/mv6UB)
- [but this will compile](http://ideone.com/ylJ6R)

And also *what i do not understand* regarding the **gcc** `c` code compiler is:

- since this code *does* compile,

```
int main () 
{
    int bar[13]={0};
    return 0;
}
```

- why this code *does not* compile..

```
int main()
{
    const int foo=13; //cpp compiler knows this really is const ! 
    int bar[foo]={0};
    return 0;
}
```

- and yet this code **does** compile?

```
int main()
{
    const int foo=13;  
    int bar[foo+1]={0}; //wtF?
    return 0;
}
```

(NB: in this last case, **MS** `c` code compilation fails; consistently as with `int bar[foo]={0};`)

Comment: On my TDM-GCC 4.6.1 the last example does **not** compile (again with "variable-sized object may not be initialized"). I also never heard of VLAs beeing initialized by an initializer list, is this even correct C? Looking into it..

Comment: For the part of your question on MS compilers this is not the only feature that is missing, they simply don't support C99. Since last year there is even a newer version of the standard, C11, so they now lack 2 major versions behind.

Comment: ..well i agree with you about the VLA initialisation question -which is why i threw in the `cpp` compilation tests.

Comment: It's never a good idea to trying to understand a C question by looking at what the C++ compiler does - as far as I know C++ doesn't even have VLAs, but this is only a GNU extension from gcc. If you really need to know if you are writing legal C code, pick up your C standard [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). And now accept Mats answer already ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

C99 §6.7.8 *Initialization* says this:

> The type of the entity to be initialized shall be an array of unknown size or an object type that is **not** a variable length array type.

So your initialization is invalid C.

The only way for `type a[size]` to *not* be a VLA is for `size` to be an *integer constant expression* (§6.7.5.2). What you have there is not an integer constant expression, so you have a VLA:

> If the size is not present, the array type is an incomplete type. If the size is * instead of being an expression, the array type is a variable length array type of unspecified size,
>   which can only be used in declarations with function prototype scope such arrays are
>   nonetheless complete types. If the size is an **integer constant expression** and the element type has a known constant size, the array type is not a variable length array type;
>   otherwise, the array type is a variable length array type.

Part §6.6/6 *Constant expressions* defines them as:

> An integer constant expression shall have integer type and shall only have operands
>   that are integer constants, enumeration constants, character constants, sizeof
>   expressions whose results are integer constants, and floating constants that are the
>   immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant expression shall only
>   convert arithmetic types to integer types, except as part of an operand to the sizeof
>   operator.

Comment: Ok. So `foo+1` cannot be an integer constant expression, since at compilation time it is not possible to certainly know the value of `foo` even if it's declared as `const`. So it's a bug in my gcc.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `clang`  supports `foo+1` as an extension: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#c_ext

Comment: It's still nagging me why in http://ideone.com/Br6cC, array `bar` is being treated as a VLA. since it can be determined at compilation time that `foo` is indeed an integer constant. infact i'm inclinded to find out what kind of assembly code actually gets generated for something like `const int foo=13;`

Comment: It doesn't matter if the compiler can determine whether it is a compile-time constant or not, the standard mandates an integer constant expression, and a `const int` value isn't one. (C++ has more complex rules with `constexpr`, but doesn't have VLAs I believe.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, for my gcc (version 4.4.4), your last example

```
int main()
{
    const int foo=13;  
    int bar[foo+1]={0}; //wtF?
    return 0;
}
```

also *does not* compile, just as one would expect.  You might want to double-check your toolchain (to verify you didn't relink an existing '.o' in there somewhere), and try again.

If you find that it really does work, here is my `gcc -v` output, perhaps you can detect a difference in the configuration and that might lend some light.

```
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch=i686 --build=i686-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.4 20100630 (Red Hat 4.4.4-10) (GCC)
```

Comment: well i get [this](http://pastebin.com/5TKnuStM) ~not really sure what should i be looking for tbh -looks like i may be falling foul of another *debian squeeze stable* effect

Comment: i still don't really undestand why `cpp` works but `c` does not. i mean i can see that the `cpp` compiler has all the info necessary to not throw an error. but is there some c-standard for specifically *not behaving the same way?

Comment: @violet313, My posting was that `cpp` _does not_ work.  Apparently you are using a different compiler, or even just a different configured copy of `cpp`.  The one you are using isn't working correctly if it allowed you to compile; it is a bug in that compiler (and if you care about portability, you shouldn't use such a construct even if you compiler allowed it).

Comment: [Edwin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/302139/edwin-buck). yes i do care about portability. i fixed my code with a #define -curiosity drove me here. +1 for your time

Comment: while i do agree with [anthales](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1250595/anthales) that `c` & `cpp` are different beasts & you say that for you the `cpp` compilation does not work, i also have [this code](http://ideone.com/ylJ6R) `cpp` compiling under **VS2008**. & note **MS** does *not do VLAs ;)

Comment: @violet313 it doesn't matter if they do VLAs or not, as the construct between the array brackets is not a VLA.  While it might not make much sense, a `const int` cannot be combined with anything to make an `integer constant expression`.  Even though you can't reassign the variable's value, the value contains a variable reference, so it isn't an `integer constant expression`.

Comment: yes. i think i had two issues: the standard (sorry Mat i sometimes suffer from tldr-itis) vs the implementation; &that i ever hit this in the first place, which seems to be a feature of *my gcc. both are now essentially resolved for me. thx all!

Answer (score -1):

As Matt has already quoted the standard, **`const` qualifier applied to an integer variable does not count as an integer constant expression**. We might wonder why? It looks as innocent as an integer constant!

This *may* be because `const` are not absolutely `consts`. You might alter their values through pointers and all a compiler might do, if at all it catches such an assignment , is throw a warning but cant really prevent you from altering the `const` value.

PS: **Don't trust the online compilers** like [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) etc. Here's one silly [runtime error](http://ideone.com/sHvWg) it throws for a very simple C program.

Comment: ha. fair point but i did originally hit the problem & then compile the tests on my *debian squeeze* -& then found that the ideone compiler did the same thing -which seemed both convenient & seemed to make the question more relevant